# Uneven edges when using plot function

Tags: plotting

Can anyone explain why these uneven edges occur when using the Plot3D function and why there's a hole in the function plotted using ContourPlot3D? Here's a [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207978/how-do-i-plot-a-plane-and-a-graph-in-one-3d-plot) to a previous question of mine, where I included pictures of the uneven edges as well as what i was trying to plot.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possibly because you need to specify more points with `PlotPoints` or more mesh iterations with `MaxRecursion`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting: lines that should be straight are curved](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/plotting-lines-that-should-be-straight-are-curved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is undersampled, increase the [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

R = 8.314;
a = 363.7*10^-3;
b = 42.7*10^-6;

Plot3D[(R T)/(V - b) - a/V^2,
 {V, 0, 0.001}, {T, 290, 320},
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 PlotRange -> {0, 12000000},
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"V", "T", "p"}),
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Exclusions -> {V == 0, T == 0},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 8]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the same `PlotPoints -> 100` with OP's `ContourPlot3D`: it almost removes "holes", but takes so much time to compute and then free rotation with mouse is very difficult :(